# Exactness of Hom functor for torus representations?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Given a reductive algebraic group $G$ and a maximal torus $T$. Is it true that the functors
$$
Hom_T(-,\lambda)
$$
are exact, where $\lambda$ denotes one of the the simple one-dimensional representations of $T$? Why is this so? I feel this should be very elementary, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you seen a proof that all representation of $T$ are semisimple?

Comment: aah, so every module is projective and injective so the functor is exact?

Comment: Indeed. The proof is not even that tricky, though it is not completely trivial.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to prove it!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading my comment to an answer to get this off the unanswered list:

The category of rational modules for a torus $T$ is semisimple (regardless of the characteristic), so all modules are projective and injective and thus all functors of the form $\operatorname{Hom}_T(-,M)$ are exact, whatever module $M$ one picks.